# Splits and Slicing on Mnist Dataset using Tensorflow Datasets load method

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, mnist

I am trying to load the MNIST dataset and I am trying to split it into three datasets, train, test and validation. the syntax should be:

```
(train, test, valid) = tfds.load('mnist', split=['train[:90%]','train[90%:]', 'test'])
```

However, when running the code, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "Invalid split train[:90%]. Available splits are: ['test', 'train']"
```

In the documentation, the following example is provided:

```
train_10pct_ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train[:10%]')
```

which throws the same error:

```
KeyError: "Invalid split train[:10%]. Available splits are: ['test', 'train']"
```

Any ideas? Did this method got deprecated? If so, any alternatives on splitting and slicing an object like this? Thank you!

Comment: I have tested the out the code above and it works just fine for me in colab, have you tried running it in colab, what version of it is in your tensorflow datasets. The colab version is 4.0.1

Comment: It's weird, I installed it with conda and it turns out the version is '1.2.0'. Maybe conda tensorflow-datasets hasn't been updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, above issue is due to `tensorflow_datasets 1.2.0`. Your issue can be resolved once you upgrade it to latest version as shown below

```
pip install tensorflow_datasets --upgrade
```

Working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
print(tfds.__version__)
(train, test, valid) = tfds.load('mnist', split=['train[:90%]','train[90%:]', 'test'])
```